# Will a review get reviewed by someone else while I'm reviewing it

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, documentation, review-queues, proposed-changes

If I spend a long time deciding whether to accept or reject a documentation edit, will someone else be able to reject or approve it in the time it takes me to decide?

Comment: Yes.  The review may even be completed before you make your choice.

Comment: @NathanOliver Wasn't this changed at some point to prevent this?

Comment: @Stijn It may have.  I haven't seen it in a while but I know a review was completed before I decided once before.

Comment: @Stijn the question you linked appears to be about suggested edits for questions and answers, I am specifically asking about suggested edits to documentation, I'm not assuming they are the same.

Comment: Then the [meta-tag:suggested-edits] tag may be inappropriate here, not sure though. I'll retract my Close Vote for now.

Comment: @JarrodDixon Can you explain what is status planned?  Are you going to lock reviews?

Comment: @NathanOliver yes, we're planning on only allowing a single reviewer at a time to review a change.  I couldn't reuse the existing blocking mechanism that other queues use, so this functionality was punted for a bit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is rolling out now.

When a proposed change is loaded, you'll have around 5 minutes before someone else can be assigned to it.

Any action you take (approve, reject, skip) will release the change back into the available pool, provided it's still reviewable.